# String scramble Coderbyte

Tags: ruby, string

I am solving this [string scramble problem](http://coderbyte.com/CodingArea/GuestEditor.php?ct=String%20Scramble&lan=Ruby) on coderbyte.com:

> [H]ave the function `StringScramble(str1,str2)` take both parameters being passed and return the string `"true"` if a portion of `str1` characters can be rearranged to match `str2`, otherwise return the string `"false"`. For example: if `str1` is `"rkqodlw"` and `str2` is `"world"` the output should return `"true"`. Punctuation and symbols will not be entered with the parameters.

Here is my complete code:

```
def StringScramble(str1,str2)
    #convert string to array
    #create an empty string
    #double iterate and add string if item is satisfies condition
    #compare

    str1= str1.split("")
    str2= str2.split("")
    str = ""

    for i in 0...str2.length
        for j in 0...str1.length
            if str2[i]==str1[j]
                str = str + str1[j]
                str1.delete_at(j)
                puts "#{str1}"
            end
        end
    end

    puts str
    if str == str2.join("")
        true
    else
        false
    end
end
```

It works for simple cases that don't have a lot of repeated letters in `str1`, but for some other cases such as

```
str1 =   "heloooolwrdlla"   #"coodrebtqqkye"
str2= "helloworld"  #"coderbyte"
StringScramble(str1,str2)
```

I get a result of `hellllooword`. The problem stems from the condition `str2[i]==str1[j]`, and I tried fixing that by deleting the element that has already been used, but it continues to add element that are repeated. The nested iterations don't stop after finding the corresponding character to add into `str`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
def StringScramble str1, str2
  str1.chars.sort.join =~ Regexp.new(str2.chars.sort.join(".*")) ?
  "true" : "false"
end

StringScramble("rkqodlw", "world") # => "true"
StringScramble("heloooolwrdlla", "helloworld") # => "true"
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I was looking for a way to effectively rearrange `str1` to match `str2`, and if `str1` and `str2` are equal, it will return true otherwise false.

Comment: That is different from what the question asks.